# Remove particle / softbody simuation to simplify scene?

Tags: particles, baking, soft-body

I have a scene where I use a softbody animation and a molecular addon particle simulation that then gets skinned via the CubeSurfer addon to form a liquid-like paste. The particle systems and the softbody do not have any direct interaction.

When I try to bake all the elements, Blender crashes midway through the animation. It is probably too complex. It is also EXTREMELY slow when playing back the animation, around 0.1 fps.

I'm trying to find a way to simplify it, i.e. convert the mesh that CubeSurfer generates into a simple animation, the same with the softbody, so that the simulation does not have to be baked or run every time when rendering. How can I achieve this?

I have the advantage that the particle system gets skinned by the CubeSurfer addon and forms one object and not tons and tons of individual particles.

Asked in another way: Baking saves the animation frames into a buffer for faster playback. Is there a way to go even further than baking? To completely remove the particle system and only have the animation use the mesh that resulted out of the simulation with keyframes?

Comment: Can you [post a `.blend` file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?